# How to add more properties to a slot on Datatables Vuetify 2.0?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

How to add two or more properties on the same slot on Datatable Vuetify 2.0
I use below code for only one property called active, but if I want to use it for few other properties means (like status, is_user and etc), how can I use that? any OR condition on v-slot

```
<template v-slot:item.active="{ item }">
   <v-icon class="font--style"> {{ item.active ? 'done' : 'clear' }} </v-icon> 
</template>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the response from [Vuetify Discord Chennal](https://discordapp.com/channels/340160225338195969/340215499398840331/604442991830237214)

We can do something like this to achieve by having a list of column names in the array,

```
let listOfColumns = ['isActive', 'isUser']
<template v-for="(column, index) in listOfColumns" #[`item.${column}`]="{ item }">
   <v-icon class="font--style" :key="index"> {{ item[column] ? 'done' : 'clear' }} </v-icon>
</template>
```

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this extended example can help you to figure it out.

Here is the link https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aeVjBK?editors=1010

```
<template v-slot:item.fat="{ item }">
    <v-icon :color="item.fat > 10 ? 'red' : 'green'">{{ item.fat > 10 ? 'done' : 'clear' }}</v-icon> 
    <span>({{item.fat}}%)</span>
</template>
```

Comment: thanks for the help!, but I just want more conditions like this `item.fat || item.status || item.active` to be added. But I don't think it is possible

Comment: Do you mean as slots? For example `<template v-slot:item.fat || item.status="{ item }">` (btw. this will not work).

Comment: In that case, you best option is probably to create new component and use it inside `v-slot` for every `item.a`, `item.b` ... `item.x` ...

Comment: Any example for the above comment would be great :)